# ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1

Tags: spring, jboss, wildfly, activemq-artemis, wildfly-23

I am trying to setup ActiveMQ Artemis with WildFly 23 in domain mode using `domain.xml` and `urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0` subsystem.
I am getting `AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` when the application is trying to request (i.e. send message) to ActiveMQ

Could you please share some thoughts I am adding here the configurations I am using.

**Domain.xml**

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:DUmmyPass}"/>
        <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
        <management jmx-enabled="true"/>
        <journal type="NIO" file-size="102400"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <remote-connector name="openwire-connector" socket-binding="messaging-openwire">
            <param name="host" value="serverIP"/>
            <param name="protocols" value="OPENWIRE"/>
        </remote-connector>
        <remote-acceptor name="openwire-acceptor" socket-binding="messaging-openwire">
            <param name="host" value="serverIP"/>
            <param name="protocols" value="OPENWIRE"/>
            <param name="connection-ttl" value="600000"/>
        </remote-acceptor>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jgroups-broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <jgroups-discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster"/>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1" min-large-message-size="1024000" message-load-balancing-type="ON_DEMAND" />
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="TEST_REQUEST_QUEUE" entries="java:/jms/queue/TEST_REQUEST_QUEUE java:jboss/exported/jms/TEST_REQUEST_QUEUE"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory1" connectors="in-vm"  connection-ttl="60000" min-large-message-size="10485760"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"  ha="true" min-large-message-size="10485760" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa" client-failure-check-period="86400000" connection-ttl="172800000" min-large-message-size="2500000" transaction="xa" statistics-enabled="true">
            <inbound-config rebalance-connections="true"/>
        </pooled-connection-factory>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:camel="http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!--    Connection Factory -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/JmsXA" expected-type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">

    </jee:jndi-lookup>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" id="jmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!--    Queue -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="test-queue" jndi-name="java:/jms/queue/TEST_REQUEST_QUEUE" expected-type="javax.jms.Destination"/>

    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.jms.Receiver" />
 

    <!-- and this is the message listener container -->
    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="com.jms.ListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="test-queue"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
        <property name="messageSelector" value="server.instance.name"></property>
        
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

ERROR Log:

```
ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)) AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:481)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.slowPathDecode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:273)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.decode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:149)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:377)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:683)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:253)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:515)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.channelRead(ProtocolHandler.java:151)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

2023-07-29 11:44:44,813 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)) AMQ222218: Server disconnecting: Error decoding buffer: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:390)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:683)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
```

Comment: What JMS library is the producer using to send the message? What port is the producer using? Can you provide the details from WildFly configuration about the `messaging-openwire` socket binding?

Comment: messaging-openwire port I am using is 7050 I have added openwire jar in module and now application is successfully deployed but I am facing new error in which it is showing ERROR : com.dummy.jms.listener.MessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ActiveMQQueue[java:/jms/queue/RESPONSE_QUEUE]' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.0:56256. Username: user; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable  NOTE: above error is still there but now I am able to deploy